# How can I track system-specific config files in a repo/project?

Tags: ruby, git, version-control

I have a ruby project, and the database host and port might be different on dev and production. I need a way to get different values for those into my scripts for the two environments.

The project should be complete - so there should be some way to specify default values. I don't want a clone to be missing the config files. So ignoring them completely won't work.

How do you solve this problem with git?

Comment: erm, keep a branch and merge 'main' into 'production' and 'development' branches? This could be done (semi)-automatically by topgit (possibly stgit as well)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would recommend using:

- a template config file (a file with variable name in place of the host and port value)
- a script able to replace those variable names with the appropriate values depending on the environment (detected by the script)

The Git solution is then a [git attribute filter driver](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) (see also [GitPro book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)).

> A filter driver consists of a `clean` command and a `smudge` command, either of which can be left unspecified.
>   Upon `checkout`, when the `smudge` command is specified, the command is fed the blob object from its standard input, and its standard output is used to update the worktree file.
>   Similarly, the `clean` command is used to convert the contents of worktree file upon check-in.

That way, the script (managed with Git) referenced by the smudge can replace all the variables by environement-specific values, while the clean script will restore its content to an untouched config file.

[image: clean smudge]

When you checkout your Git repo on a prod environment, the smudge process will produce a prod-like config file in the resulting working tree.

Comment: It seems that the link to GitPro book points to a wrong place. Possibly in current edition the chapter numbers has been changed.

Comment: Is there a way to make this the default behavior in a repository for all clones so that all the collaborators are not required to `git config ...`?

Comment: @Tarocco No: a git filter content, like other config, is best set explicitly by the user (to avoid any security issue due to some nefarious script "automagically" activated)

Comment: @VonC Thanks, good to know. Going back to the original question, is there another way to keep a file branch-specific without changing git config?

Comment: @Tarocco Actually, there is the template directory that, if shared by all team member through an accessible network path, can be used to initialize new Git repositories, including their configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377191/6309. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363618/6309 and below.

Comment: You say "That way, the script (managed with Git) referenced by the smudge". How exactly do you reference a script managed by git in the smudge filter? I'm relatively new to scripting and git filters but I would really like to get this working in my project. [How to set up a smudge or clean filter so that it references a script tracked by the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77736895/21891079).