# Is there a way to setup remote-specific .gitignores?

Tags: git, github, heroku, gitignore

Is there a simple way to setup different .gitignore files for different remotes?  I have a repository I push up to both Heroku and Github.  I need database.yml for Heroku, but don't want some of the information to be pushed up to Github.  So I need a different .gitignore file for each of the remotes.

I tried having two separate branches, one that ignores database.yml, and one that doesn't.  The problem is that when I checkout the heroku branch and go back into my github branch, the entire database.yml file is gone.

Any tips?

Comment: FunkyMunky, did you find a good solution for your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about the requirements for Heroku - hopefully Justice is right and you can simply avoid the problem. If you can't, or if someone else finds this who can't...

If you want the two remotes to be mirrors (have the same commits), they must by definition have the same files in those commits. So, you have two choices: have `file-for-repo-B` in all repositories, even if they don't need it, or use a slightly messy workflow with two branches: `master` and `for-repo-B`. The only difference between the two branches would be the commits touching `file-for-repo-B`; the branch `for-repo-B` would always merge from `master` (but never the other way around!). Now you just have a different branch checked out in repo B, and all is good.

Answer (score 10):

Do not put database information in database.yml. Instead, use Heroku environment variables.

Comment: This rule applies to any other production environment, not just heroku.

Answer (score 1):

You should versionned a:

- `database.yml` with only variables in it, and
- a script able to replace those variables by the right values depending on the remote server where that `database.yml` is deployed.

Then you use the script as a **[smudge attribute filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154948/how-can-i-track-system-specific-config-files-in-a-repo-project/2155355#2155355)**:

[image: smudge content filter]

Each time you will checkout (and create a working tree) on a remote server, the script is executed and will change the variables accordingly, giving you a custom `database.yml` file.
If one of the remote does not need that `database.yml` file, it can still be there, but emptied by the smudge script.