# Hiding settings.py passwords for Heroku Django deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku, passwords, django-settings

I have sensitive data (database passwords) in settings.py and I was advised to upload  my Django project to a github repository before pushing it to Heroku on their "Getting Started with Django on Heroku".  If I put settings.py in .gitignore, then presumably it won't get deployed with my project.  How can I prevent settings.py from being exposed but still get it deployed with my project ?

Comment: You could use different branches, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475273/git-have-different-gitignore-file-for-each-remote.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that but it sounded tedious.  I think I figured out the best way to do it, which is to use Heroku's environment variables as in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3 and then use os.config["variableName"] to retrieve the value in settings.py .   Pretty surprised this is not a more google-able problem though ...  maybe this will help

Comment: You don't need to push to github, just to git. It could even be a local git repository without any remote. In the "getting started" they just suggest to install system-wide the github .gitignore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use environment variables (with `heroku config:add SECRET=my-secret`) to setup sensitive data and retrieve them in your settings with:

```
SECRET = os.environ.get('SECRET', 'my-default-secret-key')
```

If you don't want to be able to start your app without having set up some data, use this syntax instead:

```
SECRET = os.environ['SECRET']
```

It will raise an exception if you didn't set the `SECRET` environment variable.

Comment: However, I can't find the syntax os.env anywhere, I believe it is: os.environ["HOME"]

Answer (score 2):

You should use a tool designed for factoring out sensitive data. I use YamJam https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yamjam/ . It allows all the advantages of the os.environ method but is simpler -- you still have to set those environ variables, you'll need to put them in a script/ rc file somewhere. YamJam eliminates these questions and stores these config settings in a config store outside of the project.  This allows you to have different settings for dev, staging and production.

```
  from YamJam import yamjam

  secret = yamjam()['myproject']['secret']
```

Is the basic usage. And like the os.environ method, it is not framework specific, you can use it with Django or any other app/framework. I've tried them all, multiple settings.py files, brittle logic of if/then and environment wrangling. In the end, I switched to yamjam and haven't regretted it.

Comment: This approach is much easier than creating environment variables and makes things a bit more organized, thanks for the answer!