# Django Private Files - How to hide them

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add Firebase to Django, which works perfectly. However, I have to save a credentials file with my private keys and such.

Currently I just have it saved in the project directory, however, how do I hide this file when uploading to Git for deploying onto something like Heroku?

Basically, my question is how do I hide such files. Does it have something to do with Environment variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding settings.py passwords for Heroku Django deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071977/hiding-settings-py-passwords-for-heroku-django-deployment)

Comment: Yes, you need to pass secret values via env variables. This package should help you with this: https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Comment: Interesting. How about an actual json file; how do I hide/access that? This seems more appropriate for variables. The firebase admin from Google requires me to provide a json file, which I currently have saved in the project directory.