# Different `.gitignore` for different remote repositories?

Tags: git

I want to ignore different files when pusshing from my local repository to different remote repositories. But there is only one `.gitignore` file in my local repository. What should I do?

Comment: What is the end goal that you are trying to accomplish?  There is probably a better solution than trying to juggle multiple .gitignore files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that branching is the best option in your case. Then you can just add the ignored files to a specific branch and upload that branch to the specific repository.

Although git is not mean to be used like that, since .gitignore is just a list of patterns to be ignored in the current branch, tecnically, shouldn't be different .gitignores in the same branch.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475273/git-have-different-gitignore-file-for-each-remote) is a similar situation to yours and how branching can solve this problem.

Comment: thanks. I learned that different directory in the working directory can have different `.gitignore` files. But when you say "add the ignored files to a specific branch", do you mean adding different ignored files to the same `.gitignore` file as the one before switching to a different branch,  or do you mean add different ignored files to different `.gitignore` files under different directories in the working directory?

Answer (score 1):

`.gitignore` is effective only against the working directory, thus will not be applicable after a commit has been made. And you cannot push the same history differently to different remotes. So the answer is **no, you can't** unless you follow the advice of @h0m3 and use different branches (thus split the history).