# GitLab/git automate push to another repository on push event (only some files)

Tags: android, git, gitlab

I have two GitLab repositories, one for source code and other resources for Android application, let's call it main and another repository only for translations, let's call it translations, which is also public repository. Translations are also contained in first repository which needs them for building application. Is it somehow possible to automate GitLab/git to push to translations repository only translation files from main repository when push to main repository occurs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the best idea would be to use different branch which includes seperate .gitignore for their respective remote. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10475317/3378714) link for more information. Also if you want to allow only certain files you may have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398868/3378714)