# Is there a way to hide certain files on public repo but keep it available for Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt

I have project with a config file that has private information on it, and I am using .gitignore to keep it from being shown on my public repo. I need this file for my project to work properly, so, I am unable to push my recent repo to Heroku because my project will no longer be functional. Do I have any way to have this file available to Heroku, but not to those who view my public repo?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: have different .gitignore file for each remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475273/git-have-different-gitignore-file-for-each-remote)

Comment: How would I implement that?

Comment: As Dougal explains in the excepted answer there - you should create a separate deployment branch from master, and only commit the config files in that branch. This branch is the one that would be pushed to Heroku

Comment: Sorry, must've not noticed the link there. I'll take a look, thanks!