# Checked out an old revision in git, then returned to latest revision, but deleted files from old revision are still in local directory?

Tags: git, delete-file, git-checkout, revision

While using git, I checked out a specific revision in my master branch:

`checkout <branch hash> .`

I only did this to take a look at some previous files, I made no changes.  I then attempted to reset my current state to my latest revision.  Unfortunately I attempted several commands because I wasn't sure if it initially worked; the commands included:

`checkout master .`

`checkout HEAD .`

`reset HEAD --hard`

I wasn't sure if it worked at first because of certain behavior that indicated a previous file of the old revision was present.

I then realized that my modified and new files were indeed restored to the current revision, however files that I deleted between the old revision and the current revision are still in my local directory.  Is this supposed to occur? I imagine that no one would generally want old, deleted files to be present after returning to the current revision, and yet this appears to be the case.

I was wondering if I did something wrong for this to occur or if there is another command I can use to remove these unwanted files of the temporarily checked out revision?

Comment: Your problem was the `.` path at the end of your checkout: you told it to check out that path, `.`, i.e. recursively the entire current directory, from that commit, without switching commits.  So it added the entire `master` checkout to your worktree and index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [GIT: When checking out an alternative branch, I want to clear ignored files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752025/git-when-checking-out-an-alternative-branch-i-want-to-clear-ignored-files)

I believe you're looking for the `git clean` command.  If you do a quick `git clean -nd <path>`, it will list all the un-tracked / deleted files that will be deleted upon a real run of the command.

If you're sure that includes all the files you want to delete, perform a `git clean -df <path>`.

Reference: http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html

Comment: awesome, and thanks for the link! I understand why the behavior I observed is the default now too.  Just something to note, the -f flag is also required for the actual delete command, or else I receive: "fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -n nor -f given; refusing to clean". so `git clean -df <path>` did precisely the trick!

Comment: @user1167662 Thanks; I updated the answer so anyone else looking into this will see it.