# git workflow with vendor directory

Tags: git, composer-php

I have two branches in my git repo **master** and **production**. The main difference is that in production, the **vendor** directory has been checked in and is not present in the **.gitignore**

My issue is when I switch from production to master

```
git checkout master
```

the whole vendor directory gets wipped out.

What are my options?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2692957/955926

Answer (score 4):

Try a '[`skip-worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/6309)' (from [`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)):

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- vendor
```

When on the branch `production`.
See if, when checking out the `master` branch, that directory is deleted.

Comment: @user391986 is `vendor` tracked (added and committed)?