# Stop git from re-deleting an ignored file that used to be tracked?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-rm

A [previous poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691618/git-is-deleting-an-ignored-file-when-i-switch-branches) wanted to track a file in one branch and not in another; I just want to not track it at all.

I used to have ".p4client" tracked in git, which turned out to be a mistake. So I deleted it from the repository, added the name to `.gitignore`, and recreated the file. Now it gets deleted when I switch branches -- but only some checkouts, not all. It appears to occur only when switching *to* 'master', not *from*, and not when going between dev branches.

**How can I put an stop to this, and just keep the file around, untracked?**

Comment: I found a [the?] solution to my problem while editing the question but decided to post anyway in hopes it will be useful since I didn't find an existing question about this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The deletion occurred in 'master' and has not been merged up to feature branches that already existed at that time. Thus the `git-rm` in 'master' is ahead of the commits in, say, 'de8060' and needs to be reapplied when checking out master.

### Solution

Merge 'master' into every branch it is not already an ancestor of, before re-creating ".p4client". Then git will not need to 'update' the working copy with a 'newer' delete operation each time 'master' is checked out.

Comment: Would rebasing the feature branch with master also work?

Comment: @k0pernikus since that would put the branch commits 'ahead' of the commit that deleted .p4client, I would expect it to work. And if the file has already been re-created in master, it ought to survive the process, whereas merging definitely deleted it yet again. You should post this as an answer : )