# Git delete files in .gitignore after branch switch

Tags: git, switch-statement, branch

I have two branches :

- master
- feature-x

In the project, I have a `temp` folder.
This folder is in `.gitignore`

While being in `master`, I created a file `hamburger.txt` inside the `temp` folder. 
Then I switched branch for `feature-x`.
The file `hamburger.txt` disappeared.

Then I switch back to `master`. The hamburger has disappeared definitely.

Why ? How can I get it back ?

I thought the files / folders in `.gitignore` were completely ignored by git. How switching branch could make the file disappear ?

Comment: Checking out to a branch shouldn't touch files that are ignored by git. Is the .gitignore file within both branches?

Comment: Ouch. Branch `feature-x` didn't ignore the `temp` folder... Is that why ?

Comment: No. Files should not be removed when you are switching to another branch. Could you can reproduce it?

Comment: The file should have been listed as "untracked" when switching to feature-x.

Git will only delete files that are under version controll (except you use Git clean commands or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the file back via `git-stash` : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

It seems that it is a normal behavior as explained is this possible duplicate : [Git is deleting an ignored file when i switch branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691618/git-is-deleting-an-ignored-file-when-i-switch-branches)

Please not that I sometimes used the Github App for Mac OS to commit / switch branch. Not sure if it plays a role, though.