# Modify an XML file when committing

Tags: git

i know that eclipse and netbeans don't support git hooks. Is there perhaps another way to change automatically a XML before committing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and declare a ['clean' script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154948/how-can-i-track-system-specific-config-files-in-a-repo-project/2155355#2155355) (a [gitattribute filter driver](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), described [in ProGit](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html))

[image: clean smudge]

That would allow you to change what you are committing.