# Set up a default directory structure on git init

Tags: git, templates

I would like to optimise my git workflow by automating creation of .gitignore, README, LICENSE and other files on `git init` command.

To do that I RTFM of `git init` at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init and it tells me to do one of the following:

1. Use `git init --template=<template_directory>`, but it's bothersome.
2. Alter the contents of the $GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR environment variable, but I would rather not.
3. Set the `init.templatedir` configuration variable. Now we're talking!

So I `sudo mkdir /usr/share/git-core/templates/my_template` and `touch` some files in it, then I `vim ~/.gitconfig` and append:

```
[init]
    templatedir = /usr/share/git-core/templates/my_template
```

And `git config -l` tells me:

> ...
>   init.templatedir=/usr/share/git-core/templates/my_template
>   ...

Happy with myself, I go to my development playground directory and:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /the/current/directory
$ ls -a
.   ..  .git
```

**Bummer... where are the files? :(**

Quick check:

```
$ ls -a /usr/share/git-core/templates/my_template
.   ..  .gitignore  LICENSE README.md
$ git --version
git version 1.8.2.1
```

It seems that `$ git init --template=/usr/share/git-core/templates/my_template` doesn't work either.

So what is it that I'm doing wrong here? Incorrect configuration directive? Bad template or its location (I'm on OSX)? Should template be a git repo? A bare one?

Comment: dont have time to write a full answer right now, but all template files go into the `.git` folder

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is the expected `git` behavior:

If you read the manual correctly about the template directory:

> **TEMPLATE DIRECTORY**
>
> The template directory contains files and
>   directories that will be copied to the **$GIT_DIR** after it is created.

The files which are copied from the template directory are placed in your `GIT_DIR` which defaults to the `.git` directory under your repo's root directory.

`git init` does not support templates for the work-tree as far as I know. If this behavior is required, you should be able to get away with writing some simple bash aliases or functions to do this for you.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Indeed, the files are in .git directory.

Comment: Could you create a repo that contains those starting files, then use the `.git` dir from it as your template dir?

Answer (score 12):

You can do it, but it will require a few extra steps.

1. Create your default directory structure as though it were a normal repo:

   ```
   mkdir template && cd template
   git init && touch README.md && cat ~/.gitignore_global > .gitignore
   git add --all && git commit -m "init"
   ```

(strictly speaking this last commit isn't necessary here, but you have to do them eventually, so why not now)

2. Now remove your working tree and move .git files up:

   ```
   mv .git/* ./ && rm -r README.md .gitignore .git
   ```
3. You may now set this as your default template, but for the sake of example:

   ```
   mkdir ../myrepo && cd ../myrepo
   git init --template=../template
   ```

   (Note the interesting message: `Reinitialized existing Git repository...` )
4. **Now the important step:** (your repo is up to date, but your working tree is not):

   ```
   git reset --hard
   ```

   (if you skip the commit earlier, you will have to commit here before resetting)

In the future, assuming you've set your default template, you simply

```
git init && git reset --hard
```

(I have no direct references, but [this chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) sure helps.)

Comment: If you're interested in a more detailed explanation of the plumbing that is actually happening here, I'm happy to explain, but essentially it boils down to the fact that your git objects (and packs) are actually your files (and commits and directory structure) and if you store those properly in your template, then you can recover them in any template-inited repo. And of course this can all be done with lower-level commands as well, but this way it's easier to avoid errors.

Answer (score 8):

You could create a template repository which you clone each time you want to create a new project.  You then delete the .git folder and copy the contents into your new project before calling git init.  Assuming your template repository is called project_template:

```
$ git clone project_template new_project
$ cd new_project
$ rm -rf .git
$ git init
```

Not an ideal solution, but it can be scripted.

This is a modification of the steps provided [here](http://kevinthompson.info/blog/2013/11/11/using-git-repos-as-project-templates.html), which is specific to using GitHub.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've rewritten the answer to provide information directly in the post.

Comment: What is the purpose of `cp -r ...`? You can just `git clone project_template new_project` instead.

Comment: As avoided @bummi, the link you insert is broken! :(

Comment: In GitHub Help, when it comes from [creating a repository from a template](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template) the orientation is not direct cloning that repo, but instead copy it through *Use this template* button available. This way there's no need to remove `.git` directory or run `git init`

Answer (score 4):

You might find the cookiecutter tool useful for automating the initial creation of a skeleton project based on a flexible template:

https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter

It is cross platform and actively maintained. Although it is implemented in python, it works well for any type of project and does not require any python expertise.  Best of all, you can easily share your templates via github.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution that works for me:

- Make a directory at a fixed location with what you need inside.
- Then make a script that copies its contents to where you want to initiate a git repository.

An example follows.

By the way, some common .gitignore configurations are available here: https://gist.github.com/octocat/9257657

Set up the directory:

```
mkdir ~/.git_template_dir
cd ~/.git_template_dir
echo "..." > .gitignore
```

Write the script:

*nix:

```
#!/bin/bash
git init
cp -R ~/.git_template_dir/ .
```

Windows (%userprofile% equivalent to ~; %cd% to .) :

```
git init
xcopy %userprofile%\.git_template_dir\ %cd%
```

Then add to Path for easy access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/git-templates/hooks
git config --system init.templatedir '/usr/local/share/git-templates'
```

- add the hooks you want inside the `hooks` directory

and only then issue `git init` in the root of the repository you want to update.