# Git import initial structure

Tags: git

I wonder if it is possible to do a `svn import` like command with git?
Every new repository for this project I'm working on should have two submodules, a default `.gitignore` and some empty folders.

Thanks!

EDIT:
What about this? Can I have a repository with a initial structure that I can copy/clone and rename into a new repository?

Comment: write a `bash` script

Comment: You can't have empty folders in git....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're asking, but the

```
svn import <directory>
```

equivalent in git is

```
git add <directory>
```

[Here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/images-git/7/78/Git-svn-cheatsheet.pdf) is a cheat sheet

EDIT: After understanding that OP wanted a template.

Ok, you can create a template, then when you use git init you specify the template you want to use.

it looks like somebody asked that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363460/set-up-a-default-directory-structure-on-git-init)

or you can go [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) to read the official documentation.

Also, there's nothing stoping you in creating a repo for just the template, then have everyone on your team to clone that repo so they have your template.

Comment: git add will add files for commit, not import from a repository?

Comment: oh! I get it! so you want like a template for all your repos?

Comment: After they clone that repo, how can you change the repository to push/pull from? How can you create a new one based on an old`?

Comment: You can change the remotes with git remote.

Comment: @Johannes you can have your team to clone the repo for the template in a specific location, for example, /home/guillermo/git/templates.

And then, you can tell them to work in any directory, for example, /home/guillermo/projects/

The next time they need to work in a new project they would go to 
/home/guillermo/projects/project1 
and do a

    git init --template={nameOfYourTemplate}
    git remote add origin {url that you want}