# Can I use Git subtree without a prefix?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm looking for the "right" way to start a new project always using another project (like a starter with auth, sessions, users, acls, etc, etc, already developed). Initially I created a new project with a clone and then I changed the remote 'origin' to path. I thought that subtree was the correct method to deal this issue

```
git subtree add --prefix . template master --squash
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do. Wouldn't a subtree in the root of the repository be the same as a clone of the subtree? Could you please add some details to your question?

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm looking for the "right" way to start a new project always using another project (like a starter with auth, sessions, users, acls, etc, etc, already developed).

Initially I created a new project with a clone and then I changed the remote 'origin' to path.
I thought that subtree was the correct method to deal this issue

Comment: Actually, I think your original approach is more "right" than subtree. If you don't care about the history of the parent repository, you could also use something like `git archive` to create a zip file without any history and work from that, doing `git init` again and starting new history.

Comment: @chris and what technique would you use to update the project starter on the new repository done with `git archive`?

Comment: That's why it says "if you don't care about the history". It also means "if you don't care about upstream updates". That option would give you a project that is entirely disconnected from the original.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up a default directory structure on git init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363460/set-up-a-default-directory-structure-on-git-init)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Chris provides a reasonable answer in a comment:

> If you don't care about the history of the parent repository, you
>   could also use something like `git archive` to create a zip file
>   without any history and work from that, doing `git init` again and
>   starting new history.

There is an interesting alternative here abusing `git init` templates, which are usually for setting up the `.git/` dir... [Set up a default directory structure on git init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363460/set-up-a-default-directory-structure-on-git-init)