# Creating my own Play Framework 2.x templates

Tags: playframework-2.0

Is it possible to create my own Play Framework 2.x templates?

I need to create some templates for different kind of projects, but it would be great if this templates can be used with activator.

```
$ activator new my-new-app my-company-template
```

Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activator doesn't do much more than copy an existing skeleton, the only extra thing it does is insert the project name you choose in a build.sbt file.

I would recommend creating a template, putting it on your companies git hosting site, and then get people to clone it from there when they want to create a new project. That's pretty similar to what activator new does.

Comment: I was looking too, and I found this, that is pretty similar to your solution ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363460/set-up-a-default-directory-structure-on-git-init. Thank you. Anyway, I will leave this question here, just in case in the future that feature be implemented.