# How to configure default configuration for new Git repository?

Tags: git, cygwin

In the following we see that Git set `ignorecase` to true by default despite my `.gitconfig` configuration.

```
$ mkdir foo && cd foo && git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/c/Users/nowox/home/git/foo/.git/
$ cat .git/config | grep ignore
        ignorecase = true
```

How can I tell Git to set `ignorecase` to false by default for new repositories?

I have put this config file in `$GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` (/usr/share/git-core/templates):

```
[core]
        ignorecase = false 
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
```

But it still doesn't work. It seems my `config` file is erased by Git...

### Full Example

```
~/test $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/c/test/.git/
~/test $ cat .git/config
[core]
        ignorecase = true
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true

~/test $ cat /usr/share/git-core/templates/config
[core]
        ignorecase = false
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
```

It looks it doesn't work. Both config files are different:

```
~/test $ diff  /usr/share/git-core/templates/config .git/config
2,5c2,5
<         ignorecase = false
<         repositoryformatversion = 0
<         filemode = true
<         bare = false
---
>       ignorecase = true
>       repositoryformatversion = 0
>       filemode = true
>       bare = false
```

It is the same if I declare the `GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` variable:

```
~/test $ rm -rf .git
~/test $ GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=/usr/share/git-core/templates git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/test/.git/
~/test $ cat .git/config
[core]
        ignorecase = true
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
```

Comment: By the way, `git init foo && cd $_`.  `$_` expands to the last parameter to the previous command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [TEMPLATE DIRECTORY of git-init](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory).

By default, when we initialize a new git repo, the contents under `/usr/share/git-core/templates` will be copied to this new repo's `.git`. So we can make a template for `config` here, which includes

```
[core]
    ignoreCase = false
```

For `git-bash-for-windows`, it's `/mingw64/share/git-core/templates/` or `/mingw32/share/git-core/templates/`.

Besides as the manual says, we have the folloing options to specify the templates.

1. the argument given with the `--template` option;
2. the contents of the `$GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` environment variable;
3. the `init.templateDir` configuration variable.

Comment: This does not answer the question. A file named `config` added on the template directory will be clobbered by Git during the `git init`.

Comment: @nowox Is your `$GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` or `init.templateDir` set to the value different from `/usr/share/git-core/templates`?

Comment: No it points to `usr/share/git-core/templates` and I have added a `config` file in this template dir with the `ignoreCase` set to false

Comment: @nowox It should have worked. I've tested on both Windows and Ubuntu and it works as expected. What is `.git/config` like in your failed case?

Comment: See my gist https://gist.github.com/nowox/ed1bfff6dcb7a76345091c4b77d8a092

Comment: @nowox Sorry but gist is blocked in my network. I can't open the link.

Comment: No problem, I have included that gist in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152039/discussion-between-elpiekay-and-nowox).