# Is there a way to push a template file instead of the actual file with git?

Tags: git, push, secret-key

Let's say I have a specific file structure:

```
├─root
│ ├─.git
│ │ ├─...
│ ├─config
│ │ ├─secret.keys
│ │ ├─secret.keys.template
│ │ ├─ ...
│ ├─...
│
```

I store sensitive data in `root/config/secret.keys`, and the data is formatted in a specific way. I have a template of `root/config/secret.keys` in `root/config/secret.keys.template` which contains the specific formatting in `secret.keys`, without any of the sensitive data.

Is there a way to automatically replace the data in `secret.keys` with the data in `secret.keys.template` in a git push, (obviously without actually replacing my copy of the data permanently)? If not, what's the standard way to approach this problem?

Comment: You want a hook?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I track system-specific config files in a repo/project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154948/how-can-i-track-system-specific-config-files-in-a-repo-project)